# approaches to parallelize data extraction and processing in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I would like to parallelize execution of several data processing tasks. There are several bottlenecks, which I see: 1. data extraction is time consuming, 2. execution of functions on these data is also slow.

My initial approach was to use pool.map(func()) to map function, which extracts chunks of data and processes them with *func_1* then with *func_2*, so this gave some improvement mostly on "data" based parallelism. The figure below shows approach which I use at the moment.

However, *func_1* and *func_2*, etc. are independent from each other and can also work in parallel on extracted chunks of data and deliver results to database independently from each other.

I am not sure how to approach this problem with Python. I see this as some kind of ***map*** inside ***map***. The first ***map*** maps *func()* across several processes and second parallelizes *func_1* and *func_2* inside this ***map***.

[image]

***Any suggestions on how to approach this? Some packages for such type of tasks?***

Comment: Are you sure the code and functions are optimised? Check that before working on multiprocessing/threading

Comment: IMHO, this is far too vague for StackOverflow as it is at the architectural design level rather than the coding level where StackOverflow operates. The answer would depend on far too many things - what database you use, what OS you use, how many CPU cores you have, how much memory you have, what disk subsystem(s) you have, what the processing is, how big the data-sets are, how important locality of cache is... and so on.

Comment: I have the following constrains: say 12 CPUs, 32GB RAM. The extraction cannot be made faster.I consider functions to be optimized. If it is too conceptual, it would be good to have examples of code which can show how and if it is possible to run several functions in parallel inside function which runs under pool.map().

Comment: Parallel processing in Python has some caveats that might be important here. Pools use queues to transmit data between processes. It works but it is not a miracle performer.  If the data between func_1 and func_2 is significant by volume, your code could slow down by separating them to different processes.  As pointed out, this is a vague question where no proper answers can be given but my intuition says your current approach is good as it minimises data transfer between processes when everything in the green bloc happens inside a subprocess.

Comment: If each of your three (or N) green blocks corresponds to an independent Python script, you can very simply run `N` in parallel, each with their own GIL and no interdependencies under **GNU Parallel**. Try searching for related questions with `[gnu-parallel]` in the Stack Overflow search box.

Answer (score 0):

In general I find that one of the steps dominate the others. And in that case it is fairly easy to parallelize: Make `func()` into a single program that takes the data_id to process and do:

```
number_of_data_ids=100000
seq $number_of_data_ids | parallel python my.py {}
```

This will run one `my.py` per CPU core, which is typically what you want if `func()` is computationally expensive.

It does not teach you how to do parallel programming in Python, but it will often be faster at getting the job done, because you do not have to debug the parallelizing part in Python. Instead you can focus on writing a simple single threaded program, that does the right thing for one block of data.